# What is the proper way to concatenate in php

Tags: php, html

what is the correct way to concatenate the following to something like this "Hello John - (admin)"

```
      if(has_access($session_user_id, 1) === true){
         $message[] = ' - (admin!)';
       }
 ?>
<div  id="info">

 <p class="profile"> Hello <?php echo $user_data['first_name'], . echo output_messages($message) . ;?>! </p><br /><br />
```

Thanks!

Comment: With `echo`, you can either use a comma separated list of arguments, or concatenation.... but using both is redundant, and you don't echo each element that you're concatenating

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Comment: `.` is the proper way to concatenate strings in PHP. `$string = $foo . $bar . ' (admin!)'`.

Comment: @MarkBaker: and a syntax error! :D

Comment: `echo $user_data['first_name'], output_messages($message);` or `echo $user_data['first_name'] . output_messages($message);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <p class="profile"> Hello <?php echo $user_data['first_name'] .  output_messages($message)  ;?>! </p><br /><br />
```

Comment: Thank you all! Mark and Bugaloo the example helped allot.  Thanks Rocket reference was helpful.  I can't up vote as I dont have 15 reputations yet :)